# WPF window - other controls not responding to clicks after adding Hyperlink control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, textblock

I am new to WPF,and have written a simple hello world type application in order to get started. The code I have so far is shown below:

**WPF XAXML**

```
<Window x:Name="wndMain" x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ews="clr-namespace:ExtraWindowStyles"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        ews:ExtraWindowStyles.CanMinimize="false" 
        ews:ExtraWindowStyles.CanMaximize="false"         
        Title="Hello World" Height="501.492" Width="842.285">
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="Input Parameters" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="173" Margin="10,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="801" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,96,0">
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold">First Group</Label>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt11">Option 1 - 1</RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt12">Option 1 - 2</RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt13">Option 1 - 3</RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Second Group"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt21" Content="Option 2 - 1"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt22" Content="Option 2 - 2"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="opt23" Content="Option 2 - 3"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

        </GroupBox>
        <Separator HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="17,203,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="794"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnSubmit" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="632,203,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179" Click="btnExplore_Click"  />
        <Label Content="Results:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="10,242,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161"/>
        <Label Content="My App" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="696,439,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" FontSize="9"/>
        <TextBlock>           
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
                Click Here
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="162" Margin="17,270,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="794"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblResult" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="157" Margin="17,275,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="794"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind..**

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

If I comment out the Hyperlink control XAML (and its related backend code), I am able to select options, click the Submit button etc.

However, if I uncomment the Hyperlink control (and its associated backend code), The only thing that remains clickable, is the Url on the form - what's going on?

Comment: Do you have any styles defined for `Hyperlink`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just position your `TextBlock` and it won't take all space in the window and cover everything :

```
<TextBlock Width="100" Height="30">
    <Hyperlink Background="Red" NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" >
        Click Here
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Because the `TextBlock` is after submit button in XAML it is over.
You could also set Margin to position the `TextBlock`

***Layout knowledge***
Elements in a grid Stretch Horizontally and Vertically if no alignment is set.

***Useful tip*** : If you click on the `TextBlock` tag, you'll see the extent of the TextBlock in the design view.
Often useful